# How can we divide the price if the customer select certain attributes?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am working on a magazine site where the magazine can be subscribed. When users subscribe, we want to allow them to choose between full payment and monthly payment. I have used a "payment_type" attribute for the payment option, and I want to divide the total price by the number of months when user selects the monthly payment option.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module? It is great for that kind of automation.